# Do scriptures allow to worship idol of acharya?

Tags: scripture, guru

Do scriptures allow to worship idol/photo of an acharya/guru?

Answer (score 3):

yes, they do.

Sri Krishna in Gita:

> देवद्विजगुरुप्राज्ञपूजनं शौचमार्जवम्।
>
> ब्रह्मचर्यमहिंसा च शारीरं तप उच्यते।।17.14।।

So He mentions Gurupuja as one essential part of tapasya.

Sweta-ashwatara-Upanishad says(6/23)

> Guru and deity should be respected equally.

Gurugita says:

> Dhyanamulam gurormurth (Sri Sri Guru-Mahimamrita,
> ie The meditation of image of Guru is the highest meditation.

Mundamalatantra says

> Gurupujaam vina devi ishtapujam karoti yah/mantrasya tasya tejamshi vairabhah harate swayam.

Rudrayamaltantra says

> Gurupujaam vina naatha kotipunyam vrith vyayam.

All of our scriptures make Gurupuja essential before every worship for initiated people.

Reference: Sri Sri Guru-Mahimamrita, Omkarnath Rachanavali,vol 9, page 1-199, THE ENTIRE BOOK IS ON GLORY OF GURU)